# Can I update my TableView items one a time without blocking UI thread?

Tags: java, javafx, observable

I have two methods. The first retrieves a list of results from a search method in another class.

```
/* 2 - Retrieve list of results */
qmitResultsList = QMITSearchUtil.execute(URL, keyword);

/* 3 - Show results */
populateTable(qmitResultsList, tableView)
```

The second, `populateTable()` adds all the items to the table at once by calling:

```
ObservableList<QMITResult> dataPriority = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        qmitResultsList
);
tableView.setItems(dataPriority);
```

My goal is to add each new element to the TableView as it is being processed in real-time. For example, instead of processing and returning the entire list in the first method, `QMITSearchUtil.execute()`, I would like to update the UI with each result that is returned, one at a time. How can this be accomplished? I've tried a few ways, using a `Platform.runLater()` hack for example, with no success...

Comment: You would do this by retrieving the results in a background thread and adding each one to the table in `Platform.runLater()` (assuming that doesn't invoke `Platform.runLater(...)` too frequently). Why are you referring to `Platform.runLater(...)` as a hack? This is essentially exactly what it is deigned for.

Comment: I'll try to retrieve what I did and show what I've attempted.

Comment: `populateTable(qmitResultsList, tableView)`: This looks like you're updating the list backing the `ObservableList` instead of the `ObservableList` itself which results in no notifications being triggered by the `ObservableList` which means the `TableView` won't "see" any changes (unless you're never modifying the list and only updating elements that are already in the list)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the answer to my question. I first define the ObservableList for my TableView:

```
ObservableList<QMITResult> dataPriority = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

Then I pass that into the `execute()` method that runs the background thread:

```
private void execute(String URL, String keyword, ObservableList<QMITResult> dataPriority) throws Exception {

        /* Download HTML page and create list of URLs from relevant links */
        Elements links = getLinkList(URL);

        List<QMITResult> qmitResults = new ArrayList<>();

        new Thread(() -> {
            for (Element link : links) {
                try {

                    /* Create a list of formatted URLs to loop through */
                    String linkText = link.toString();
                    String titleText = link.text();
                    String formattedLink = StringUtils.substringBetween(linkText, "<a href=\"", "\"").replace("\\", "/");

                    System.out.println(titleText);
                    System.out.println(formattedLink);

                    /* Create Word Document for each link and parse for keyword */
                    QMITResult qmitResultNode = null;
                    try {
                        qmitResultNode = parseDocument(keyword, formattedLink, titleText);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    qmitResults.add(qmitResultNode);
                    dataPriority.add(qmitResultNode);
                    Thread.sleep(200);


                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

        tableView.setItems(dataPriority);

    }
```

The result is that while the list is being formed each TableView item is being individually published without blocking the main UI thread. They come one at a time.

Comment: This is the answer to my question. I was just working on it and got it working.

Comment: Okay. I thought you were updating your question. Sorry!

Comment: Well, the answer is not correct. You are updating the UI from a background thread, which is not allowed by the JavaFX threading rules. You need to wrap the call to `dataPriority.add(qmitResultNode)` in `Platform.runLater(...)`.

Comment: @James_D Really? Which rule does it violate and how? As far I can see I'm retrieving the results in a non-blocking way.

Comment: `dataPriority.add(qmitResultNode)` causes the table view to update, because you have set `dataPriority` as the table's backing list. You're calling that on a background thread, which violates the rule that you cannot modify the UI from a background thread.